# Bind on change event to a <select> populated by ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have in my projects two  elements, the first one have a change listener that populates the second one like this.

```
<select id="user_id" style="width: 100%;">
     <option value=""></option>
     <?php foreach ($clients as $client) : ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $client['Client']['id'] ?>"><?php echo $client['Client']['name'] ?></option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<select id="pet_id" style="width: 100%;" disabled>
     <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

--

```
$('#user_id').change(function() {
    var client = {
        client_id: $(this).val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo Router::url(array ('controller' => 'grooming', 'action' => 'getClientById')); ?>",
        data: client,
        success: function(data)
        {
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            if (json.result === "success") {

                    $('#pet_id').select2('data', null);
                    $('#pet_id').empty();

                    $.each(json.list, function() 
                    {
                        $('#pet_id').append($("<option/>").val(this.breed_id).text(this.name));
                    });

                    if(!$('#pet_id').is(':enabled')){
                        $('#pet_id').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }

            }
            else
            {
                    $('#pet_id').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#pet_id').select2('data', null);
                    $('#pet_id').empty();
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Now I have to add another change listener to the second selector (#pet_id) but it is not working any of these alternatives.

```
$('#pet_id').on('change',function (){
    alert('finally worked :)');
});

$('#pet_id').bind('change',function (){
    alert('finally worked :)');
});
```

¿What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any reason you're using `.change()` for #user_id, and then switching to trying .on/.bind for #pet_id?

Comment: Where are you adding the new events in your code?

Comment: @MarcB Because I'm populating #pet_id with an ajax request, I've already tried it but doesn't work neither.

Comment: @MicahHenning I have one <script> in the html page.

Comment: Did you do it inside $(document).ready?

Comment: And outside of `$('#user_id').change(...)` too, right?

Comment: @KhanhTO Yes, it is on $(document).ready(function()) and it is outside $('#user_id').change(...)

Comment: Tried to reproduce with a fiddle, seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/AstDerek/Dfz26/

Comment: @AstDerek I realized that this is happening because I'm using select2 libraries, I don't know why but it is working fine without them. Thank you all!